# Associated graded ring of p-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

How can one describe the associated graded ring of $\mathbb Z_p$ with respect to its maximal ideal $p\mathbb Z_p$? If one follows the definition, the associated graded ring is
$$\mathrm{gr}_{p\mathbb Z_p}\mathbb Z_p = \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty p^n\mathbb Z_p/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z_p$$
Here each summand $p^n\mathbb Z_p/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z_p$ is isomorphic to the finite field $\mathbb F_p$. So additively the graded ring is just infinitely many copies of $\mathbb F_p$, and the multiplicative structure is defined with respect to the grading.

Is there some way to give a more conceptual description of the graded ring here? Is it perhaps isomorphic to some nice ring?

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_p[x]{}{}$

Comment: Similarly you'll get $k[x]$ for any DVR with residue field $k$.